# Ruby On Rails 3 - Atom Feed Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, atom-feed

I am getting this error that has to do with the db. Any ideas how to solve it?

/app/views/articles/feed.atom.builder:

```ruby
atom_feed :language => 'en-gb' do |feed|
  feed.title "My Blog"
  feed.updated @articles.first.accepted

  @articles.each do |article|
    feed.entry article, :published => article.accepted do | entry |
      entry.title article.title
      entry.summary article.teaser + '<br /><br />Read the full article: <a href="' + article_url(article) + '">' + article_url(article) + '</a><br /><br />', :type => 'html'

      entry.author do |author|
        author.name article.user.fullname
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The error:

```
/app/views/articles/feed.atom.builder where line #5 raised:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: articles.state: SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."state" IN ('3', '4') ORDER BY accepted desc LIMIT 1
Extracted source (around line #5):

    2: 
    3: atom_feed :language => 'en-gb' do |feed|
    4:   feed.title "My Blog"
    5:   feed.updated @articles.first.accepted
    6:               
    7:   @articles.each do |article|
    8:     feed.entry article, :published => article.accepted do | entry |
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are following [my article](http://www.communityguides.eu/articles/14), then it is this line in the controller and your model misses the attribute state: `@articles = Article.where(:state => ['3', '4']).order('accepted desc')`

Edit: Just remove the where and use Article.order('...')

Comment: Good guess, was following your article! I tried this but its still not working @articles = Article.order('accepted desc'). Is this what you meant?

Comment: If you have a field named accepted of type datetime in your model, yes. Otherwise, take created_at. In this case, you need to change the atom_feed too, accepted is used there.

It might be easier to start with the basic example at the top of the page and customize this one after it is working...

Comment: Sorry, you've lost me there...?

Comment: The article you followed is a full tutorial, in total 12 articles. The feed is a feed of all articles on CommunityGuides. To select those articles, I take all articles that are published, that means, have a state of 3 and 4. This is the code from above. I assume (of course I don't know) that your model is different and you simply do not have a field state or accepted in your model. Therefore you need to use fields you have and as Rails automatically generates a timestamp I suggested to take created_at and to remove the where clause. Try @articles = Article.order('created_at desc').

Comment: @markus I have installed step 1 and 2 of your article, still nothing working - where it says use @articles = Article.order('created_at desc') I have already have   @articles = Article.published.page(params[:page]).per(5).ordered - is this causing the issue?

Comment: This looks like you are trying pagination in a feed...that's weird. Start with a simple query like mine and then add what you need to add - however, without pagination.

Comment: The pagination is part of my index page as that's where the articles are?

Comment: That's fine for your index view in html, you still do not want pagination in the feed. In my article there is an additional method for the feed.